# Xamarin not start AVD when Add WebService in 5.5

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

My Xamarin not start after app has been updated to versio 5.5. The following warning appears:

**Warning XA4211: AndroidManifest.xml //uses-sdk/@android:targetSdkVersion '15' is less than $(TargetFrameworkVersion) 'v4.5'. Using API-L for ACW compilation. (XA4211)**

My AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="MyApp_App.MyApp_App">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
<application android:label="MyApp" android:icon="@drawable/icon"></application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue.  Did you find an answer?

Comment: @Zuzlx yes, I downloaded the tools_r23.0.2 version and replace  in tools directory "AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk".